# Lighting Issue in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was experimenting with the Nodus client on 1.8.3 and tried out x-ray mode, whenever that is enabled the chunks auto refresh. When I turn it off, I have lighting issues in my single player world even with the vanilla launcher, as shown below (click to enlarge).

[image: Nighttime3]
[image: Daytime]
[image: Nighttime1]

Areas that should not be lit at all are always bright.

I currently have no idea how to fix this and it is rather annoying having areas completely bright. I tried placing torches in areas and breaking them but that did not work out. I also tried doing F3 + auto refresh chunks and other debug tools.

Is there any way that I can fix this or am I stuck with this issue?

Comment: Is there anyway that I can fix this or is it a permanent problem

Comment: What part of the image has lighting issues? The color difference is biome based i believe

Comment: @ModDL OP seems to mean the fullbright, not the biome change. It's most evident to the right of the image where the farm under the roof is still completely lit.

Comment: Is this lighting problem still present on a vanilla client, or only when you use the world with nodus?

Comment: @colorfusion The above photo was taken with Optifine and that is all. The issue persists for the whole chunk (I believe) because everything underground is fully lit up. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/3IOhp8A.png) is a night picture with a vanilla client. [This](http://i.imgur.com/x73sCEx.png) is the area to the left of the cursor in the original image. And [this](http://i.imgur.com/fHzCjIw.png) is an area in the distance that is another example of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when a player burns down a large chunk of forest at once. This can be easily fixed by using [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/) to relight those chunks:

1. Open the world in MCEdit via `Quick Load` or `Open...` buttons
2. Select `Chunk control` in the toolbar
3. Select the chunks to relight
4. Click `Relight`
5. Save the world: `Menu` > `Save`

[image: example]